# Does Bachet's conjecture hold if the numbers that are squared are required to be unique?

Tags: sums-of-squares

Some backstory, forgive me for not having any kind of mathematical background:

A friend of mine received an optional programming assignment to write an algorithm to find the four squares that sum to a given 5-digit number. The professor asserted that for every number there will be a solution.
However, he added the constraint that all numbers must be unique amongst themselves.

I started playing with it, and for both the recursive and loop-based function I wrote, I got the following list of counterexamples when uniqueness was enforced:

```
12288
16384
18432
24576
28672
32768
45056
49152
65536
73728
98304
```

Is this an error in my programming, or does the conjecture indeed not hold when this constraint is included?

Comment: Powers of 2 never have all four component squares unique, so the onclusion of 16384, 33768 and 65536 is correct.

Comment: All of these numbers are multiples of $2048 = 2^{11}$, which is interesting.

Comment: Dividing by that factor gives 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16, 22, 24, 32, 36, 48.  Out of these, 14 can itself be expressed with unique squares ($3^2+2^2+1^2+0^2$), but multiplying by an odd-exponent power of two causes pairing up for that case and uniqueness is lost.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for the observations. You'll probably have saved a few students a headache 

Comment: "unique" is an unlucky formulation. You probably mean "distinct perfect squares". "unique" would mean that there is essentially only one way to represent the number as the sum of $4$ squares.